# change value format in database column

Tags: mysql, bitcoin

OK here's my scenario--
I am updating a bitcoin faucet.  In my database there is a column for visitor's balance.  Pre-update, balances were formatted like 12345 but with the update, I want them like 0.0012345 with a leading zero followed by 8 digits.  Basically the column is in satoshis and I need to change them to Bitcoin values.
Some users only have 10, while others have 50000, but they all need to be updated to x.xxxxxxxx format and I have no idea how to do change these values without going through each of the 10,000 entries manually.
So, here's my question:
How do I modify the values of entire columns to the new format, from satoshis, to bitcoins, while still keeping the data intact?  All I want to do is add a leading digit, a decimal point then how ever many more zero's to make current balances a total of 8 digits past the decimal point.
Please help, and I hope someone in the bitcoin world understands what I'm trying to do here and can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straightforward.

```
UPDATE table SET balance = balance / 10000000
```

Comment: so say if a user has a balance of 10 but i want it to be 0.00000010 just running that sql command will do this?

Comment: No, 10/10000000 is 0.000001. You said 12345 should turn into 0.0012345, not 0.00012345. This is is simple mathematics. This query will update **all** users.

Comment: oops i forgot a zero... but i expanded further down the paragraph when i specified that the end result should be 8 digits past the decimal for all values in the column

Comment: thank you ceejay, i am new to this so bear with me... so have a table named "balances" and within that table i have a column called "balance" and in that column are the values which i want to change... you're telling me that using UPDATE table SET balance = balance / 100000000 will automatically do what i want? i also have another table called "dispenses" and within that table i have a column named "amount" so to change the values in that column i would just word it like UPDATE table SET amount = amount / 100000000?

Comment: well, i got antsy and ran it and it first gave me a #1064 error so i changed the word "table" to the name of my table and it changed all values in that column to big fat zeros... so much for it being simple math... thanks anyways ceejay... your condescension is much appreciated

Comment: C'mon, dude. Your column needs to be able to store decimal data - is it an `INT`? Of course you have to change `table` to whatever **your** table is named. *Use your brain.*